# how do I set Braven 805 bluetooth as my second rank speaker after headphones?

Tags: audio, headphones

Since starting to set up my system and learning to use a DAW I have had to learn more about sound control than I ever thought I would. I want to set up when I plug in my headphones, it routes to that, so I have realtek as my default and that works. However, when I unplug them, it reverts to my puny laptop speakers and not my nice ones, which can either be connected via bluetooth or via normal headphone jack.  I want Realtek default when headphones are plugged in otherwise another default. With conditionals (if, when) being such a part of code, I hope this is possible.

Comment: The problem is that the jack and the speakers are actually the same audio device, so you can never fallback from it unless you remove it entirely.

Comment: Thanks that answers my question succinctly and awesomely! Just a bummer that they coudn't design it better, but it just tells me I have more to learn (when is that ever not the case).